# Microsoft Power Apps - Bad Gateway Error on App that was working

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

The app was working for a few days until today and suddenly is giving a 502 bad gateway error.

I've tried restoring the app to a previous version, and deleting the data from the Data tab then re-adding it. I've also duplicated the Screen and tried to delete each datacard to see if the error was related to one of them, but I'm still getting the error even after deleting every datacard. There also haven't been any changes to the list columns recently so I'm not sure what is causing this error. The code below is where the error is occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated!

FormScreen > SharePointForm > Advanced > Item >

```
 If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected),First([@'Process Documentation Mockup']),SharePointIntegration.Selected)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was resolved by going into list settings > form settings > select Use default SharePoint form > OK

Then, go back to the form settings > select Use a custom form created in PowerApps > OK